# Combine Multiple Arrays + Variable into single JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want combine two arrays and two constant values to an single json object.

my Arrays:
arraywithperson=[Alfredo, James, John, Sarah,   Vladimir ]

arraywithduration=[1,5,3,1,4]

variables:
start_date = Date.today

parent = 1

```
My Json Output should be:
    {"data": [
           {"person": "Alfredo", "start_date" = 22.01.2020, "duration": 1, "parent": "1"}
           {"person": "James", "start_date" = 22.01.2020, "duration": 5, "parent": "1"}
           {"person": "John", "start_date" = 22.01.2020, "duration": 3, "parent": "1"}
           {"person": "Sarah", "start_date" = 22.01.2020, "duration": 1, "parent": "1"}
           {"person": "Vladimir", "start_date" = 22.01.2020, "duration": 4, "parent": "1"}
           ]}
```

How can i combine the arrays with my variables that i can get this json output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` and map for that:

```
output = arraywithduration.zip(arraywithperson).map do |duration, person|
           {
             'person': person,
             'start_date': start_date,
             'duration': duration,
             'parent': parent
           }
         end
{ 'data': output }
```

With `zip` you can merge the elements of `arraywithduration` and the elements of `arraywithperson` into an array of 2 elements, inside a "main" array:

```
# [[1, "Alfredo"], [5, "James"], [3, "John"], [1, "Sarah"], [4, "Vladimir"]]
```

And `map` allows you to iterate over each element and create a hash with the keys and values you need:

```
# [{:person=>"Alfredo",  :start_date=>"22.01.2020", :duration=>1, :parent=>1},         
#  {:person=>"James",    :start_date=>"22.01.2020", :duration=>5, :parent=>1}, 
#  {:person=>"John",     :start_date=>"22.01.2020", :duration=>3, :parent=>1}, 
#  {:person=>"Sarah",    :start_date=>"22.01.2020", :duration=>1, :parent=>1}, 
#  {:person=>"Vladimir", :start_date=>"22.01.2020", :duration=>4, :parent=>1}]
```

To get the start_date as you show in your expected output you can use `strftime` (it's a String BTW):

```
start_date = Date.today.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```